# Getting "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'" when trying to install tensorflow serving

Tags: bash, tensorflow, installation

I was trying to install TensorFlow-Serving by following this [offical documentation :](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker)

I copied and pasted this command into my Ubuntu 18.04 terminal:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] <a href="http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt">http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt</a> stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && \
curl <a href="https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg">https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg</a> | sudo apt-key add -
```

But I get this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I have never used `curl`, but I know the shell will interpret unquoted `<` and `>` as redirection operators, and `|` as pipelines. Maybe that's indeed what you meant when you wrote the command, but just leaving my two cents here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** You copied html tags like `<a href="">` which shouldn't be part of the command.

### Quick Fix

Remove the html tags from the command:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && \
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

### Details

Angle brackets are used for redirection in bash.
`cmd < file` reads `file` and passes its contents to `cmd`.
`cmd > file` writes the output of `cmd` into `file`.

In the first command you were lucky: all `<` and `>` where quoted with `"`, therefore the command executed "normally" (it didn't do what you expected, but at least it didn't fail).

The second command does some stuff and ends with `> |`. You can reproduce this error with `echo > | cat`. Bash expects a file name after `>` but only found the start of another command (`| ...`).